# Node.js 203 that threw only on my PC,is that relate to any environment and can I reset that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

So there's the thing:

I was going through an example of Nodejs-express-angular:[example from Brian Ford](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email) the other day and it worked just fine.

update:----------------this part of problem has been solved----------

But after couple of hours(I may or may not have installed couple of soft wares for other purpose which I cannot recall during that time,but I didn't make any change to the codes at all) when I came back to run that example again,it threw me this:

```
node.js:203
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'zlib'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:318:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:263:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:341:17)
    at require (module.js:352:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Morf\Desktop\angular-express-blog-master\nod
e_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\compress.js:14:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:416:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:434:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:335:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:294:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:341:17)
```

Cause thers's no module as "zlib" in the codes so I thought that I might accidentally break nodejs, express or angularjs anything I'm using. So I go ahead and reinstall/redownload them all and the problem still there.

---

And I ran the same example on my friend's PC which turned out working just fine.

So I guessed that might be something relate to the working environment that Nodejs using?But I can't find any documentation about that or that just isn't a thing.
Hope someone can help me fix this or give me some advise/suggest.

Thx ahead.

update:So, Thanks to @Matt Bakaitis and @vkurchatkin , node seems working just fine as before and no longer throw error. But awkwardly the example still not fully working on my PC,

first it threw `Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute` which can be easily solved by adding "angular-route.js" and declare dependency like `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);`.

After that there's no error being report by chrome or node,the `ng-view` part just simply stop working.It's out of the scope of the original question though.So I guess I can say the question is solved.But if anyone's willing to answer or giving suggestion or assumption about the new coming up problems I describe will be much appreciate.

Still the example have been run perfectly on my PC and still function well on other's.Does anyone have a clue what leads to that?(I'm using windows 7+webstorm)

Comment: Did you remember to run `npm install`?

Comment: what node version are you running?

Comment: @Explosion Pills,Yes I've run that,not only the first time it works but for every attempt. Does that means that's something wrong with my npm? But I've tried update npm@leatest and reinstall node, still doesn't fix that.

Comment: Thanks to vkurchatkin and Matt Bakaitis, I found out the problem is that somehow there's two Nodejs installed(which is so wired considering that I just installed one myself), and I've been uninstall-install-update the one that not being called by command 'node'.My stupid problem is sloved now thanks again to @vkurchatkin and Matt Bakaitis.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a dependency (zlib). Run `npm install`.

Comment: I've run     npm install,so if that's a dependency does that mean that my npm is broken?But seems reinstall Node doesn't fix that.

Comment: Zlib is included with node.  a simple `require` should suffice.  [zlib docs](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html)

Comment: @Matt Bakaitis ,Thanks for the link but:1,the codes are not using the Zlib module at all & I tried 'require' and it still doesn't work. 2,there's no module.js too, so those should be the dependencies? Do you have any idea what will lead to dependencies dis-function or not-being-installed? Thx.

Comment: As @vkurchatkin asked in the original question, what version of node are you running?  The project you linked uses zlib because it's a dependency of connect.js ... which is a dependency of the version of express.js that the example that you linked uses.